# Difference between creating Jquery plugins with $fn and without it

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm looking on some `Jquery plugins`,and I want to build my own. In all tutorials I see syntax like this:

```
(function($) {
  $.fn.myPlugIN = function() {
    // Add plugin code here
  };
})(jQuery);
```

But when I look at the code of few popular plugins like iScroll.js, Carousel,js
I see the dont use the $.fn syntax, they write it inside one function

```
(function(){
function iScroll (el, options) {
    var that = this, i;
    //some code
    }
    })();
```

What are the difference between those function and the use of them?

Comment: Is your second code snippet complete? As it currently stands, it doesn't look like `iScroll()` is exposed to the outside world.

Comment: It seems it's just a little snippet form a NON-jQuery module, which somewhere in it's anon. function sets one global variable pointing to a constructor function. We know it, not so important that that line is not shown.

Comment: it's very simple - if the plugin doesn't add to `$.fn` (for element handlers) or `$` (for utility functions), it _isn't_ a jQuery plugin!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`iScroll` (and I'm assuming `Carousel` as well) are not jQuery plugins, so their code-behind syntax will be a bit different.

A jQuery plugin is an *extension function* that works off jQuery objects. For example, if I create a `foo` jQuery plugin, I should be able to use that via something like `$('#some-element').foo();`.

To be able to work this way, jQuery plugins extend the `$` prototype by adding functions to the `$.fn` variable like so:

```
$.fn.foo = function () {
    // foo!
};
```

`iScroll`, on the other hand, is not a jQuery plugin. It doesn't work off a jQuery object, so you don't expect it to work like `$('#some-element').iScroll();`. You use it by invoking `iScroll()` itself.

```
var obj = new iScroll('container');
```

As you'd expect, the difference in means of use will dictate different ways of declaring the plugin in its script file.

Answer (score 3):

That's the difference between a jQuery plugin and a basic javascript plugin (or module).

**iScroll doesn't use jQuery**, it has no reason to be defined as a jQuery plugin. Like most javascript plugins not based on a specific framework, it's based on the very convenient [module pattern](http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/3/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth) which lets you define many private variables not cluttering the global namespace. The snippet you show doesn't contain the part where a unique variable is exported in the global namespace.

See [source](https://github.com/cubiq/iscroll/blob/master/src/iscroll.js) :

```
if (typeof exports !== 'undefined') exports.iScroll = iScroll;
else window.iScroll = iScroll;
```

Comment: You really need to explain this answer more, this is not a proper answer.

Comment: absolutely love to know something.

Comment: I think it summarizes it quite nicely, actually.

Comment: @JonTaylor That's really the one and only reason. If your component doesn't use a technology, it can't be defined as a plugin of this technology.

Comment: @dystroy You have edited your answer since I first commented.  However an explination as to why `$.fn.myPlugIn` makes it a jQuery plugin would be useful as this is not really clear, at least not to me.

Comment: @JonTaylor the OP already showed the "normal" pattern for a jQuery plugin in the question.  No need to expand on it here, IMHO.

Comment: @Alnitak I can see that, but what I want to know is why is this considered the "normal" pattern for a jQuery plugin, and why this is used over the second option which was also shown in the OP.  I think it's only fair that if someone asks what the difference is between two things we don't just state what it is but what the actual difference is and why in this context one is better than the other, or even if one is not recomended etc.

Comment: @JonTaylor I disagree.  The jQuery plugin pattern is very well documented, and easily recognised.  The answer really doesn't need to be any more than "because the second example _isn't_ a jQuery plugin".

Comment: Look at @Richard Neil Ilagan answer, this is a good explination, one which actually has valuable information in it and shows the person has taken time to actually try and explain why one is used over the other.

Comment: @Alnitak For certain people yes it may be obvious, however for others an explanation like Richards is a much much better one, it didn't take him long to write, it explains the point, and explains why one would code a plugin in such a way.  I really don't see why this is so difficult to understand.

Comment: Besides it really doesn't matter anymore anyway since he updated his answer.

Comment: Thank's guys...I got the idea, one is jQuery plugin and the second isn't.